# Change or access ribbon property dynamically from JS in Office web add-in

Tags: office-js

In Office Web Add-in, I'd like to access and change a ribbon title dynamically from JavaScript. This is ideal in toggle buttons (two states ~ two different texts to show one at a time).

I have done some research but can't seem to find anything interesting. Is that possible in web add-in's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently supported by Office.js. All of your Add-in Commands need to be pre-defined within your manifest.

I would recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) site. There are several variations of this suggestion on there that could use more votes.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Knowing any limitation will help us achieve a good native design. I'll put a vote later on what I think should be supported.